# Prove compact subsets are not infinite

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

> If there exists $i>0$ such that for every $x,y\in M$ with $x\neq y$ we have $i\le d(x,y)$, then compact subsets of this metric space are not infinite.

My try: It is known that a discrete space is compact if and only if it is finite. So I try to prove that this metric space is also a discrete space and I got stuck.

Comment: This is false, just because you stated it incorrectly. You want to assume that there exists $i>0$ such that for _every_ $x,y\in M$ with $x\ne y$ we have $i<d(x,y)$.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Yes, I have changed it, thank you!

Comment: It should not be too hard to show that $M$ is discrete. What definition of discreteness are you working with?

Comment: First, I would say to not use $i$ in this definition, since right now $i$ is a fixed lower bound on the distance between two points. In order to connect this with metric spaces, you need to look at the definition of convergence. What definition do you use for "$(x_n)$ converges to $x$"?

Comment: "There always exist $i$ such that $x_n$ cannot converge to a point $x$." I don't understand what this sentence says since the part after "such that" doesn't mention $i$. Anyway, my point was just that you shouldn't overuse the letter $i$. Your assumption is that $i$ is fixed real number such that $d(x,y)>i$ for all distinct $x,y$. So later when you talk about convergent sequences you shouldn't write "if $i\geq n$ then $x_i=x$" since now $i$ is being used for two very different things.

Comment: Anyway, the point is this. *By definition*, a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to a point $x$ if for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some $N$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$. So now suppose $(x_n)$ converges to $x$. To prove discreteness (using your definition) you want to show that $x_n=x$ for all sufficiently large $n$. So apply the definition of convergence and set $\epsilon$ equal to $i$. You get $N$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $d(x_n,x)<i$. What do you conclude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The following answer is a recap of the discussion below the question.)

As you say in the post, it suffices to prove that $M$ is discrete. Evidently your definition of discreteness (for a metric space) is:

**Def.** $M$ is *discrete* if any convergent sequence in $M$ is eventually constant (i.e., if $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ then there is some $N$ such that $x_n=x$ for all $n\geq N$).

We can prove that $M$ satisfies this property. Suppose $(x_n)$ converges to $x$. Since $M$ is a metric space, this means that for all $\epsilon>0$, there is some $N$ such that $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. Apply this with $\epsilon=i$. Then we get $N$ such that $d(x_n,x)<i$ for all $n\geq N$. By the assumption on $i$, this means $x_n=x$ for all $n\geq N$, which is what we wanted to show.

**Remark.** (elaborating on the answer by Paul Frost) Another definition of discreteness, which works for any topological space, is that $M$ is discrete iff for any $x\in M$, the singleton set $\{x\}$ is open. This is also easy to prove from your assumption on $M$. Indeed, if $x\in M$ then $\{x\}$ is the open ball of radius $i$ centered at $x$ (since, for any $y\in M$, $d(x,y)<i$ iff $x=y$).

Comment: Got it! One question: how we use the statement that $i<=d(x,y)$ for $x\neq y$ in M? If $i<=d(x_n,x)<i$, what that means?

Comment: You **only** know $d(x,y)\geq i$ when $x$ and $y$ are **not equal**. In the proof, we don't start out knowing, for a given $n$, whether or not $x_n$ and $x$ are equal. This is the whole point. The proof shows that, for $n$ large enough, $d(x_n,x)$ is **less than** $i$, and so our initial assumption tells us that $x_n$ and $x$ **cannot** be distinct, hence $x_n=x$.

Comment: Now i'm clear that is a discrete space, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*
Let's try a proof by contradiction. Suppose that $C\subset M$ is infinite and compact in $M$. Since $C$ is infinite, we can construct a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of distinct elements in $C$, right? But since $C$ is compact, that means $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$  has a subsequence $(x_{k_n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ which converges, say $x_{k_n}\to x\in C$. Can we arrive at a contradiction using the notion of convergence and the property in the problem above?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is that: suppose $i=\epsilon$, d(x_{k_n},y)<i due to convergence, but in the question $i<=d(x,y)$. Then it is a contradiction. But what is the function of $C$ is infinite?

Comment: @maiyuqiang Yes, that is precisely the contradiction! Which function are you referring to?

Comment: I am a little confused about why we suppose $C$ is infinite? It is used to construct a sequence of distinct elements. But why this kind of sequence cannot converge to a constant in discrete metric space? And if $C$ is finite, then how can we know a sequence in it can converge to a constant?

Comment: @maiyuqiang Oh, that is how we start a proof by contradiction! We assume both the hypothesis and the negation of the conclusion, i.e. "*Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that the distance property above holds AND that there exists some $C$ which is both compact and infinite*" If $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{NN}}$ is composed of distinct elements, then it can not be a constant sequence by construction :)

Comment: Got it!! Thank you!!

Comment: @maiyuqiang happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Under your assumption $M$ has the *discrete topology* which means that all one-point subsets $\{x\}$ are open. In fact, in a metric space all *open balls* $B_r(x) = \{ y \in M \mid d(x,y) < r\}$ with $x \in M$ and $r > 0$ are open subsets. In your case we have $B_i(x) = \{x\}$.

Now let $K \subset M$ be compact. But $\mathcal U = \{ \{x\} \mid x \in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$ and must have a finite subcover. This means that $K$ is finite.